# Does the beginPath() and closePath() have to be in the code to draw an arc in HTML5?

Tags: html, canvas

I am just starting with HTML5 and was drawing a circle on the screen. Tthe arc will draw if the beginPath() and the closePath() are present but it will not draw the circle if the beginPath and the closePath are not present.

Is there a way around that that will let you draw the arc without having to place the beginPath() and closePath() in the code. I have heard at some point a person will be able to go back through the beginPath and closePath like in an array but it has not been implemented in any of the browsers at this point.

Code:

```
context.beginPath();
   context.arc(ball.x,ball.y,ball.radius,0,Math.PI*2,true);
context.closePath();
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you do next:

1. If you want to stroke the arc then `closePath()` is required to have end point and start point connected (if a circle is what you're after). If you want an open arc then it's not required.
2. If you want to fill the arc it's not required as fill will close it for you (internally)

`beginPath()` is necessary to start a clean path. If you don't use this and is for example stroking or filling, then adding more paths (ie. the arc) both the old path and the new arc will be filled/stroked again.

If the arc is the first shape added to the canvas then `beginPath()` is not required as the path is empty. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852071/what-does-beginpath-and-closepath-do-exactly/22857893#22857893) for details on what they do.

Also, just in case, when you add paths you will need to `stroke()` and/or `fill()` it to rasterize it to canvas as they only exists as internal vectors (ie. paths and sub-paths) up to that point.