# Why doesn't my code loop the animation correctly with Javascript and HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, setinterval

I'm super new to coding and I've been trying to figure out animations with Javascript and HTML5. I have this "loading bar" like animation where a rectangle expands until it fills up the canvas. The idea is that once the canvas is covered the box clears and starts over. Instead, the rectangle fills the canvas and just starts flickering. Any ideas?

```
window.onload = function() {
  var wipeWidth = 0
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  console.log(context);

  function drawRect() {
    context.clearRect(0,0,300,150)
    context.fillStyle = "#305ef2";
    context.rect(0, 0, wipeWidth, 150);
    context.fill()
    wipeWidth += 10
    if(wipeWidth > 300) {
      wipeWidth = 0;
    }
  }

  setInterval(drawRect,50)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to clear the path (`beginPath`). You can use `fillRect` instead to avoid this.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var wipeWidth = 0
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  console.log(context);

  function drawRect() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 150)
    context.fillStyle = "#305ef2";
    // this
    context.beginPath()
    context.rect(0, 0, wipeWidth, 150);
    context.fill()
    // or just this
    // context.fillRect(0, 0, wipeWidth, 150);
    wipeWidth += 10
    if (wipeWidth > 300) {
      wipeWidth = 0;
    }
  }

  setInterval(drawRect, 50)
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: `context.closePath()` is not required in your code. It is not the adjunct  of `beginPath`

Comment: @Blindman67 true, leaving explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22857893/5089567

Answer (score 0):

`fillRect`, `requestAnimationFrame`

```js
var wipeWidth = 0
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var direction = +10;

function drawRect() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.fillStyle = "#305ef2";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, wipeWidth, 150);
  wipeWidth += direction
  if (wipeWidth > canvas.width || wipeWidth < 0) {
    direction *= -1;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(drawRect)
}

drawRect()
```

```css
canvas {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="50"></canvas>
```